# Move container cub according to mouse movement

Tags: actionscript-3

As of now I have created new Container cub in which I have added all of my objects and map. So when user moves the mouse right, I move the container cub to left so it looks all stuff moves to left. Code:

```
var pt:Point = new Point(character.x, character.y);
pt = dori.localToGlobal(pt);
if (pt.x > (stage.width * 0.5))
{
                    container.x -= 5;
}
```

When mouse goes beyond middle of stage...it creates distance between mouse location and character..!! I mean it does move according to mouse but some distance get created between mouse and character. and this distance keeps increasing as I continue to move mouse away from center of stage!!Help Please!

Comment: Why don't you remove the last `if` statement? Should do.

Answer (score 1):

use linear interpolation to determine how your objects should move. for example, if when the mouse is at `x=stage.stageWidth`, bg should be at `stage.stageWidth-bg.width` and when the mouse is at `x=0`, bg should be at `0` use:

```
paramF(bg,stage.stageWidth,stage.stageWidth-bg.width,0,0);

//in a loop that updates with mouse movement:
bg.x=bg.m*mouseX+bg.b;

function paramF(mc:MovieClip,x1:Number,y1:Number,x2:Number,y2:Number):void{
    mc.m=(y1-y2)/(x1-x2);
    mc.b=y1-mc.m*x1;
}
```